# Why say imru amein at end of silent amida?

Tags: prayer-book

"v'imru amein" appears at the end of the sentence "Oseh shalom bimromov..." at the end of the silent (individual) amida.  That seems a bit odd for two reasons: We are saying amein to our own davening, and it is in the plural but we are not addressing other people.  Why is this amein in the siddur?

Comment: Interestingly, I see it in the Sechel Tov (in discussions of minhagei aveilt) as הוא יעשה שלום עלינו ועל כל ישראל אמן, and the Seder of R. Amram Gaon (hilchot se'udah) has עושה שלום במרומיו הוא יעשה שלום על כל ישראל, but אלהי נצור, יהיו לרצון אמרי פי והגיון לבי לפניך ה' צורי וגואלי, עושה שלום במרומיו, ברחמיו הוא יעשה שלום עלינו ועל כל ישראל. אמן for Y"K davening. The Beit Yosef on Yitro has a comment א"כ הקב"ה עושה שלום שהוא בעל השלום, על כן אנחנו מתפללים עושה שלום במרומיו הוא יעשה שלום עלינו.